# Falha de segmentação ao tentar inicializar lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, falha-de-segmentação

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct
{
  int codigo;
  /*
     outros componentes
     de produto
  */
} TProduto;

typedef struct celula
{
  TProduto item;
  struct celula* prox;
} TCelula;

typedef struct
{
  TCelula* primeiro;
  TCelula* ultimo;
  int tamanho;
} TLista;

void FLVazia(TLista *Lista)
{
  Lista -> primeiro = (TCelula *) malloc(sizeof(TCelula));
  Lista -> ultimo = Lista -> primeiro;
  Lista -> primeiro -> prox = NULL;
  Lista -> tamanho = 0;
}

int Vazia(TLista Lista)
{
  return (Lista.primeiro == Lista.ultimo);
}

void Inserir(TProduto x, TLista *Lista)
{
  Lista -> ultimo -> prox = (TCelula *) malloc(sizeof(TCelula));
  Lista -> ultimo = Lista -> ultimo -> prox;
  Lista -> ultimo -> item = x;
  Lista -> ultimo -> prox = NULL;
  Lista -> tamanho++;
}

TCelula* Pesquisar(TLista Lista, TProduto Item)
{
   TCelula* Aux;
   Aux = Lista.primeiro;
   while(Aux->prox != NULL)
   {
      if(Aux->prox->item.codigo == Item.codigo)
         return Aux;
      Aux = Aux->prox;
   }
   return NULL;
}

void Excluir(TLista *Lista, TProduto *Item)
{
  /* Obs.: o item a ser retirado e o apontado por p */
  TCelula *Aux1, *Aux2;
  Aux1 = Pesquisar(*Lista, *Item);
  if (Aux1 != NULL)
  {
     Aux2 = Aux1->prox;
     Aux1->prox = Aux2 -> prox;
     *Item = Aux2->item;
     if (Aux1->prox == NULL)
        Lista->ultimo = Aux1;
     free(Aux2);
     Lista->tamanho--;
  }
}

void Imprimir(TLista Lista)
{
  TCelula* Aux;
  Aux = Lista.primeiro -> prox;
  while (Aux != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n", Aux->item.codigo);
    Aux = Aux -> prox;
  }
}

int main ()
{
    //1
    TLista *Lista1;
    TProduto Item;
    //2
    FLVazia(Lista1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Estou tentando inicializar esta lista encadeada mas quando eu chamo a função *"FLVazia"* para fazer isso, ocorre um erro de *falha de segmentação*.
Eu tentei inicializar *Lista1* como NULL (Lista1 = NULL;) antes de chamar a devida função mas como esperado, nada mudou e obtive o mesmo erro.

O que está causando isso?

Isto é uma parte de um trabalho da faculdade cujo só estou responsável pela função *main*, todo o resto foi feito pelo meu professor de Algoritmos e Estrutura de Dados 1.
Desde já, obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está derreferenciando um ponteiro nulo quando faz:

```
Lista -> primeiro = ...
```

Na função `FLVazia` você deve verificar se Lista é ponteiro para nulo e, se for, fazer esse ponteiro apontar para algo:

```
void FLVazia(TLista *Lista)
{
  if (Lista == NULL) Lista = (Lista *) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
  Lista -> primeiro = (TCelula *) malloc(sizeof(TCelula));
  Lista -> ultimo = Lista -> primeiro;
  Lista -> primeiro -> prox = NULL;
  Lista -> tamanho = 0;
}
```

Mas se você já espera uma lista vazia nessa função, então não precisa do `if`, apenas alocar memória para o ponteiro (`Lista`) apontar.